# slice my sqlite table according to date

Tags: sqlite

How to select the latest two days from a table when the timestamps are in milliseconds since 1970-01-01.This is how my schema of my table looks like:

```
.schema clicks_train_
CREATE TABLE clicks_train_(
  display_id TEXT,
  ad_id TEXT,
  clicked TEXT,
  timestamp TEXT
);
```

Comment: When I try to convert one row to readable format I get an error. SELECT datetime(SELECT timestamp FROM clicks_train_ WHERE rowid=100,'unixepoch'); Error: near "SELECT": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

timestamp needs to be integer not text
here is an example I use since you don't show yours (it is reading the chrome browser history file)

```
SELECT ROUND((JULIANDAY('NOW')-JULIANDAY(DATETIME((last_visit_time/1000000)-11644473600, 'UNIXEPOCH')))*1440/60,1) AS "hours ago",url FROM urls WHERE url NOT LIKE "file:///%" ORDER BY last_visit_time;
```